# How can I case fold a string in Rust?

Tags: unicode, rust

I'm writing a simple full text search library, and need case folding to check if two words are equal. For this use case, the existing [`.to_lowercase()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_lowercase) and [`.to_uppercase()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_uppercase) methods are [not enough](https://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Case_folding).

From a quick search of crates.io, I can find libraries for normalization and word splitting but not case folding. `regex-syntax` does have [case folding code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex_syntax/struct.CharClass.html), but it's not exposed in its API.

Comment: What exactly is insufficient about those methods? It's hard to answer your question without knowing the problem you're trying to solve. There are also methods defined on char: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_lowercase

Comment: @BurntSushi5 I've added some context to the question -- hope it helps.

Comment: Your best bet is probably https://docs.rs/caseless/0.1.1/caseless/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today (2023) the [caseless](https://crates.io/crates/caseless) crate looks unmaintained, while the [ICU4X project](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu4x/docs/icu/) seems the way to go. To apply case folding see the [`icu_casemap`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu4x/docs/icu_casemap/) crate. To compare strings according to language-dependent conventions, see the [`icu_collator`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu4x/docs/icu_collator/) crate. For a good introduction on how to correctly sort words in Rust, see [here](https://sts10.github.io/2023/01/29/sorting-words-alphabetically-rust.html).

For documentation on Unicode theory and algorithms, see the [Unicode Standard](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/).
In particular:

- Case conversion and case folding: sections [3.13](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/ch03.pdf#G33992) and [5.18](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/ch05.pdf#G21180).
- [Collation algorithm](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/)

For documentation on the ICU4X project, see [here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu4x/docs/icu/).

To use ICU4X, you can either add the main crate `icu` to `Cargo.toml` and access the single modules (for instance `icu::collator`, `icu::datetime`, etc), or otherwise add just the single crates that you actually need (for instance `icu_collator`, `icu_datetime`, etc).

To check if two words are equal regardless from case, you can apply full case folding to the strings and then check binary equality. For this you likely want `icu_casemap::CaseMapper::fold_string`. Recent versions of ICU4X include the requisite Unicode data compiled directly into the library by default, but there are [other options available](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu4x/docs/icu_provider/constructors/index.html).

Here is a simple example of using `icu_casemap::CaseMapper`:

```rust
use icu_casemap::CaseMapper;

let cm = CaseMapper::new();

// Check if two strings are equivalent case insensitively
assert_eq!(cm.fold_string("hEllO WorLd"), cm.fold_string("HELLO worlD"));

assert_eq!(cm.fold_string("hEllO WorLd"), "hello world");
assert_eq!(cm.fold_string("Γειά σου Κόσμε"), "γειά σου κόσμε");
assert_eq!(cm.fold_string("नमस्ते दुनिया"), "नमस्ते दुनिया");
assert_eq!(cm.fold_string("Привет мир"), "привет мир");
```

Note that currently the `icu_casemap` crate does not include normalization, this may be added in future, see discussion [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu4x/issues/3151#issuecomment-1457835904).

Otherwise to compare strings according to language-dependent conventions you can use the `icu_collator` crate, which allows to customize several options such as strengths and locale. You can find several examples [here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu4x/docs/icu_collator/).

Answer (score 3):

For my use case, I've found the [caseless](https://crates.io/crates/caseless) crate to be most useful.

As far as I know, this is the only library which supports normalization. This is important when you want e.g. "㎒" (U+3392 SQUARE MHZ) and "mhz" to match. See [Chapter 3 - Default Caseless Matching](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch03.pdf) in the Unicode Standard for details on how this works.

Here's some example code that matches a string case-insensitively:

```
extern crate caseless;
use caseless::Caseless;

let a = "100 ㎒";
let b = "100 mhz";

// These strings don't match with just case folding,
// but do match after compatibility (NFKD) normalization
assert!(!caseless::default_caseless_match_str(a, b));
assert!(caseless::compatibility_caseless_match_str(a, b));
```

To get the case folded string directly, you can use the `default_case_fold_str` function:

```
let s = "Twilight Sparkle ちゃん";
assert_eq!(caseless::default_case_fold_str(s), "twilight sparkle ちゃん");
```

Caseless doesn't expose a corresponding function that normalizes as well, but you can write one using the [unicode-normalization](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-normalization) crate:

```
extern crate unicode_normalization;
use caseless::Caseless;
use unicode_normalization::UnicodeNormalization;

fn compatibility_case_fold(s: &str) -> String {
    s.nfd().default_case_fold().nfkd().default_case_fold().nfkd().collect()
}

let a = "100 ㎒";
assert_eq!(compatibility_case_fold(a), "100 mhz");
```

Note that multiple rounds of normalization and case folding are needed for a correct result.

(Thanks to BurntSushi5 for pointing me to this library.)

Comment: This answer is five years old. Would you do it differently today?

Comment: @ccleve See this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75526819/59081

Answer (score 2):

The [unicase](https://github.com/seanmonstar/unicase) crate doesn't expose case folding directly, but it provides a generic wrapper type that implements `Eq`, `Ord` and `Hash` in a case insensitive manner. Additionally, it supports both ASCII case folding (as an optimization) and Unicode case folding (though only invariant case folding is supported).

This crate didn't get any updates between 2019 and 2023, but as of 2023, it is being updated for new versions of the Unicode standard.

Answer (score 2):

If someone did want to stick to the standard library, I wanted some actual data
on this. I pulled [the full list](//stackoverflow.com/questions/11124705#65433126) of two byte characters that fail with
`to_lowercase` or `to_uppercase`. I then ran this test:

```rust
fn lowercase(left: char, right: char) -> bool {
   for c in left.to_lowercase() {
      for d in right.to_lowercase() {
         if c == d { return true }
      }
   }
   false
}

fn uppercase(left: char, right: char) -> bool {
   for c in left.to_uppercase() {
      for d in right.to_uppercase() {
         if c == d { return true }
      }
   }
   false
}

fn main() {
   let pairs = &[
      &['\u{00E5}','\u{212B}'],&['\u{00C5}','\u{212B}'],&['\u{0399}','\u{1FBE}'],
      &['\u{03B9}','\u{1FBE}'],&['\u{03B2}','\u{03D0}'],&['\u{03B5}','\u{03F5}'],
      &['\u{03B8}','\u{03D1}'],&['\u{03B8}','\u{03F4}'],&['\u{03D1}','\u{03F4}'],
      &['\u{03B9}','\u{1FBE}'],&['\u{0345}','\u{03B9}'],&['\u{0345}','\u{1FBE}'],
      &['\u{03BA}','\u{03F0}'],&['\u{00B5}','\u{03BC}'],&['\u{03C0}','\u{03D6}'],
      &['\u{03C1}','\u{03F1}'],&['\u{03C2}','\u{03C3}'],&['\u{03C6}','\u{03D5}'],
      &['\u{03C9}','\u{2126}'],&['\u{0392}','\u{03D0}'],&['\u{0395}','\u{03F5}'],
      &['\u{03D1}','\u{03F4}'],&['\u{0398}','\u{03D1}'],&['\u{0398}','\u{03F4}'],
      &['\u{0345}','\u{1FBE}'],&['\u{0345}','\u{0399}'],&['\u{0399}','\u{1FBE}'],
      &['\u{039A}','\u{03F0}'],&['\u{00B5}','\u{039C}'],&['\u{03A0}','\u{03D6}'],
      &['\u{03A1}','\u{03F1}'],&['\u{03A3}','\u{03C2}'],&['\u{03A6}','\u{03D5}'],
      &['\u{03A9}','\u{2126}'],&['\u{0398}','\u{03F4}'],&['\u{03B8}','\u{03F4}'],
      &['\u{03B8}','\u{03D1}'],&['\u{0398}','\u{03D1}'],&['\u{0432}','\u{1C80}'],
      &['\u{0434}','\u{1C81}'],&['\u{043E}','\u{1C82}'],&['\u{0441}','\u{1C83}'],
      &['\u{0442}','\u{1C84}'],&['\u{0442}','\u{1C85}'],&['\u{1C84}','\u{1C85}'],
      &['\u{044A}','\u{1C86}'],&['\u{0412}','\u{1C80}'],&['\u{0414}','\u{1C81}'],
      &['\u{041E}','\u{1C82}'],&['\u{0421}','\u{1C83}'],&['\u{1C84}','\u{1C85}'],
      &['\u{0422}','\u{1C84}'],&['\u{0422}','\u{1C85}'],&['\u{042A}','\u{1C86}'],
      &['\u{0463}','\u{1C87}'],&['\u{0462}','\u{1C87}']
   ];

   let (mut upper, mut lower) = (0, 0);

   for pair in pairs.iter() {
      print!("U+{:04X} ", pair[0] as u32);
      print!("U+{:04X} pass: ", pair[1] as u32);
      if uppercase(pair[0], pair[1]) {
         print!("to_uppercase ");
         upper += 1;
      } else {
         print!("             ");
      }
      if lowercase(pair[0], pair[1]) {
         print!("to_lowercase");
         lower += 1;
      }
      println!();
   }

   println!("upper pass: {}, lower pass: {}", upper, lower);
}
```

Result below. Interestingly, one of the pairs fails with both. But based on this,
**to_uppercase is the best option**.

```
U+00E5 U+212B pass:              to_lowercase
U+00C5 U+212B pass:              to_lowercase
U+0399 U+1FBE pass: to_uppercase
U+03B9 U+1FBE pass: to_uppercase
U+03B2 U+03D0 pass: to_uppercase
U+03B5 U+03F5 pass: to_uppercase
U+03B8 U+03D1 pass: to_uppercase
U+03B8 U+03F4 pass:              to_lowercase
U+03D1 U+03F4 pass:
U+03B9 U+1FBE pass: to_uppercase
U+0345 U+03B9 pass: to_uppercase
U+0345 U+1FBE pass: to_uppercase
U+03BA U+03F0 pass: to_uppercase
U+00B5 U+03BC pass: to_uppercase
U+03C0 U+03D6 pass: to_uppercase
U+03C1 U+03F1 pass: to_uppercase
U+03C2 U+03C3 pass: to_uppercase
U+03C6 U+03D5 pass: to_uppercase
U+03C9 U+2126 pass:              to_lowercase
U+0392 U+03D0 pass: to_uppercase
U+0395 U+03F5 pass: to_uppercase
U+03D1 U+03F4 pass:
U+0398 U+03D1 pass: to_uppercase
U+0398 U+03F4 pass:              to_lowercase
U+0345 U+1FBE pass: to_uppercase
U+0345 U+0399 pass: to_uppercase
U+0399 U+1FBE pass: to_uppercase
U+039A U+03F0 pass: to_uppercase
U+00B5 U+039C pass: to_uppercase
U+03A0 U+03D6 pass: to_uppercase
U+03A1 U+03F1 pass: to_uppercase
U+03A3 U+03C2 pass: to_uppercase
U+03A6 U+03D5 pass: to_uppercase
U+03A9 U+2126 pass:              to_lowercase
U+0398 U+03F4 pass:              to_lowercase
U+03B8 U+03F4 pass:              to_lowercase
U+03B8 U+03D1 pass: to_uppercase
U+0398 U+03D1 pass: to_uppercase
U+0432 U+1C80 pass: to_uppercase
U+0434 U+1C81 pass: to_uppercase
U+043E U+1C82 pass: to_uppercase
U+0441 U+1C83 pass: to_uppercase
U+0442 U+1C84 pass: to_uppercase
U+0442 U+1C85 pass: to_uppercase
U+1C84 U+1C85 pass: to_uppercase
U+044A U+1C86 pass: to_uppercase
U+0412 U+1C80 pass: to_uppercase
U+0414 U+1C81 pass: to_uppercase
U+041E U+1C82 pass: to_uppercase
U+0421 U+1C83 pass: to_uppercase
U+1C84 U+1C85 pass: to_uppercase
U+0422 U+1C84 pass: to_uppercase
U+0422 U+1C85 pass: to_uppercase
U+042A U+1C86 pass: to_uppercase
U+0463 U+1C87 pass: to_uppercase
U+0462 U+1C87 pass: to_uppercase
upper pass: 46, lower pass: 8
```