# Case-insensitive string matching in Rust

Tags: string, rust

Is there a simple way to use [`str::matches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.matches) **case-insensitively**?

Comment: Convert both strings to lowercase first using `fn to_lowercase(&self) -> String`

Comment: *If I want to get the occurrences count of a string* — `matches(...).count()`

Comment: If you just want to do a case-insensitive string comparison with ASCII strings, then use [eq_ignore_ascii_case](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.eq_ignore_ascii_case).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can always convert both strings to the same casing. This will work for some cases:

```rust
let needle = "μτς";
let haystack = "ΜΤΣ";

let needle = needle.to_lowercase();
let haystack = haystack.to_lowercase();

for i in haystack.matches(&needle) {
    println!("{:?}", i);
}
```

See also [`str::to_ascii_lowercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_ascii_lowercase) for ASCII-only variants.

In other cases, the regex crate [might do enough case-folding](https://docs.rs/regex/1.4.3/regex/struct.RegexBuilder.html#method.case_insensitive) (potentially [Unicode](https://docs.rs/regex/1.4.3/regex/struct.RegexBuilder.html#method.unicode)) for you:

```rust
use regex::RegexBuilder; // 1.4.3

fn main() {
    let needle = "μτς";
    let haystack = "ΜΤΣ";

    let needle = RegexBuilder::new(needle)
        .case_insensitive(true)
        .build()
        .expect("Invalid Regex");

    for i in needle.find_iter(haystack) {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
}
```

However, remember that ultimately Rust's strings are **UTF-8**. Yes, you need to deal with all of UTF-8. This means that picking upper- or lower-case might change your results. Likewise, the only correct way to change text casing [requires that you know the *language* of the text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I); it's not an inherent property of the bytes. Yes, you can have strings which contain emoji and other exciting things [beyond the Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

See also:

- [How can I case fold a string in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40250988/155423)
- [Why is capitalizing the first letter of a string so convoluted in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38406793/155423)

Comment: I know it wasn't meant like this, but statements like "other exciting things beyond the Basic Multilingual Plane" really has sort of lovecraftian connotations. As if strings, like the old gods, are beyond human comprehension and to delve into a _true_ understanding of them would drive you insane. After the rust book introduced me to the notion of grapheme clusters... I kind of agree!

Comment: Question is about strings, so [`escape`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.3/regex/fn.escape.html) function could be useful: `RegexBuilder::new(regex::escape(needle))`

Answer (score 9):

If you're using [the regex crate](https://crates.io/crates/regex), you can make the pattern case insensitive:

```
let re = Regex::new("(?i)μτς").unwrap();
let mat = re.find("ΜΤΣ").unwrap();
```