# What is an efficient way to compare strings while ignoring case?

Tags: string, rust, case-insensitive

To compare two `String`s, ignoring case, it looks like I first need to convert to a lower case version of the string:

```
let a_lower = a.to_lowercase();
let b_lower = b.to_lowercase();
a_lower.cmp(&b_lower)
```

Is there a method that compares strings, ignoring case, **without** creating the temporary lower case strings, i.e. that iterates over the characters, performs the to-lowercase conversion there and compares the result?

Comment: See also [Case-insensitive string matching in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47298336/155423)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in method, but you can write one to do exactly as you described, assuming you only care about ASCII input.

```
use itertools::{EitherOrBoth::*, Itertools as _}; // 0.9.0
use std::cmp::Ordering;

fn cmp_ignore_case_ascii(a: &str, b: &str) -> Ordering {
    a.bytes()
        .zip_longest(b.bytes())
        .map(|ab| match ab {
            Left(_) => Ordering::Greater,
            Right(_) => Ordering::Less,
            Both(a, b) => a.to_ascii_lowercase().cmp(&b.to_ascii_lowercase()),
        })
        .find(|&ordering| ordering != Ordering::Equal)
        .unwrap_or(Ordering::Equal)
}
```

As some comments below have pointed out, case-insensitive comparison is not going to work properly for UTF-8, without operating on the whole string, and even then there are multiple representations of some case conversions, which could give unexpected results.

With those caveats, the following will work for a lot of extra cases compared with the ASCII version above (e.g. most accented Latin characters) and may be satisfactory, depending on your requirements:

```
fn cmp_ignore_case_utf8(a: &str, b: &str) -> Ordering {
    a.chars()
        .flat_map(char::to_lowercase)
        .zip_longest(b.chars().flat_map(char::to_lowercase))
        .map(|ab| match ab {
            Left(_) => Ordering::Greater,
            Right(_) => Ordering::Less,
            Both(a, b) => a.cmp(&b),
        })
        .find(|&ordering| ordering != Ordering::Equal)
        .unwrap_or(Ordering::Equal)
}
```

Comment: Any method that uses `str::chars` will not compare unicode strings properly.

Comment: To complement what I believe mcarton is talking about: `str::chars` iterates codepoints, but because of *precomposition* it's possible to have strings which are *canonically equivalent* but have different contents at a technical level. `chars` will not take that information in account. An other large issue is that case conversion is locale-dependent e.g. the lowercase of `I` is `i`… unless you're in turkic where it's ı. I'm sure there are other pitfalls there.

Comment: I'm not trying to compare for equality, but for <, == or >. BTW, is `string.to_lowercase()` considering the locale, so that one char could become multiple chars?

Comment: @ThomasS. please read [Why is capitalizing the first letter of a string so convoluted in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38406793/155423)

Comment: "assuming you only care about ASCII input" is awfully bad practice these days.

Answer (score 6):

If you are only working with ASCII, you can use [`eq_ignore_ascii_case`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.eq_ignore_ascii_case):

```rust
assert!("Ferris".eq_ignore_ascii_case("FERRIS"));
```

Comment: If it is about strings, e.g. from user input or file names, this does not help. How often strings are only within the application and fully under programmer's control?

Comment: @ThomasS. True, but it is still a valid answer and may be useful to some people.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I am comparing against a set of constant ASCII strings against whatever the user input is, so if that's not ASCII, then it wouldn't be a match anyway.

Answer (score 1):

### UNICODE

The best way for supporting UNICODE is using `to_lowercase()` or `to_uppercase()`.

This is because UNICODE has many caveats and these functions handles most situations. There are some locale specific strings not handled correctly.

```rust
let left = "first".to_string();
let right = "FiRsT".to_string();

assert!(left.to_lowercase() == right.to_lowercase());
```

##### Efficiency

It is possible to iterate and return on first non-equal character, so in essence you only allocate one character at a time. However iterating using `chars` function does not account for all situations UNICODE can throw at us.

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63871601/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-compare-strings-while-ignoring-case/63871901?r=Saves_UserSavesList#63871901) by [Peter Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493729/peter-hall) for details on this.

### ASCII

Most efficient if only using ASCII is to use [eq_ignore_ascii_case](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.eq_ignore_ascii_case) (as per [Ibraheem Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8858995/ibraheem-ahmed)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63871601/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-compare-strings-while-ignoring-case/65959603?r=Saves_UserSavesList#65959603)). This is does not allocate/copy temporaries.

This is only good if your code controls at least one side of the comparison and you are certain that it will only include ASCII.

```rust
assert!("Ferris".eq_ignore_ascii_case("FERRIS"));
```

### Locale

Rusts case functions are best effort regarding locales and do not handle all locales. To support proper internationalisation, you will need to look for other crates that do this.