# Unable to bound lifetime in for each loop using str.lines() function

Tags: string, rust, iterator, ownership, for-in-loop

I'm new to rust and i'm building an implementation of the grep command to learn this language.
I'm trying to create a function to match the search query in a case insensitive way, but i'm having trouble handling the lifetime of the value returned by `str.lines()` iterator in the for loop.

this is a minimal reproducible example containing the function i'm implementing:

```rust
use grep::{run, Config};
use std::{env::args, process};

pub struct Config {
    file_path: String,
    query: String,
}
fn main() {
    let contents: Config =Config {query: "Hello world!".to_owned(), file_path: "test".to_owned()};
    let matches = search_case_sensitive(&config, &contents);
    print_matches(&matches);
    Ok(config)
}

type Match<'a> = Vec<(&'a str, &'a str, &'a str)>;

// this function causes the compile error
// contents -> the full text content of the file i previously read
// config.query -> the string i'm searching for inside contents
fn search_case_insensitive<'a>(config: &Config, contents: &'a str) -> Match<'a> {
    let mut matches: Match<'a> = Vec::new();
    let query = config.query.to_lowercase();
    for line in contents.lines() {
        let indexes = line.to_lowercase().match_indices(&query);
        for (i, found) in indexes {
            let prev = &line[..i];
            let next = &line[i + found.len()..];
            matches.push((prev, found, next));
        }
    }
    matches
}
```

and i get this error when compiling:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:34:23
   |
34 |         let indexes = line.to_lowercase().match_indices(&query);
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                      - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                       |
   |                       creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
35 |         for (i, found) in indexes {
   |                           ------- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

from what I understand, `line` should be bounded to the `'a` lifetime because it is a reference to every element of `contents`, but this is not happening, so `line` is not borrowed but moved and i does not live long enough to be used in `indexes`.

How can I instead borrow line from contents and bound it to the `'a` lifetime?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman i edited my question with a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `line.to_lowercase()` is local to the function, but you're returning it.

The easiest fix is to make an owned `String`:

```rust
type Match<'a> = Vec<(&'a str, String, &'a str)>;

// contents -> the full text content of the file i previously read
// config.query -> the string i'm searching for inside contents
fn search_case_insensitive<'a>(config: &Config, contents: &'a str) -> Match<'a> {
    let mut matches: Match<'a> = Vec::new();
    let query = config.query.to_lowercase();
    for line in contents.lines() {
        let line_lowercased = line.to_lowercase();
        let indexes = line_lowercased.match_indices(&query);
        for (i, found) in indexes {
            let prev = &line[..i];
            let next = &line[i + found.len()..];
            matches.push((prev, found.to_owned(), next));
        }
    }
    matches
}
```

However, note that your code is still incorrect. Specifically, `to_lowercase()` can change character indices, and even in general [lowercasing two strings and comparing them is not enough for a case-insensitive comparison with respect to Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250988/how-can-i-case-fold-a-string-in-rust).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it solved my problem!